# Mask layer (onclick) stuck in Internet Explorer 9 and 10

Tags: javascript, onclick, internet-explorer-9, mask, internet-explorer-10

I attached an "onclick" event on a simple login submit button, which displays a mask regarding the wrapper div size. However if I click fast on the button twice in Internet Explorer 9 and 10, the mask is stuck there. I have not experienced this kind of issue in any other browsers.

I created a simple demo:
http://nagyhonlap.hu/IE9-10Mask/index.html

Does anybody know how to fix this problem, but also keep the original functionality?

Comment: Javascript should generally be set inside of <head>-elements (else you  should use <CDATA>. You could try to move the js-code there. You could also try using onready with Jquery.

Comment: I think it does not matter where this mask() function is, hence it is not injecting third party javascript code, just use it. However I tried to move it in the head section, also to use <CDATA>, but still has the same issue. I want this feature on click event, not onready.

Comment: I can't get the problem to occur in IE9 or IE10, no matter how fast or slow I click the second time. But if you want to protect against this, how about disabling the submit button in addition to putting up the mask layer?

Comment: I also tried to disable the button first, then put the mask. Still the same issue. Also to remove the onclick event via jQuery removeAttr(), still the same. I reproduced it on an another machine too. If you clicking repeatedly fast on the login button, the mask (redirecting...) is stuck on the page. I updated the test page with the above disable modification...

Comment: your link works fine at my end